# Backing up files to external drive with rsync

Tags: backup, rsync

So my scenario is that I have been using rsync to backup files from an internal drive to an external USB drive. The backup is only about 50% done and I want to backup the remaining files to a second, larger drive and then add the files from the first drive later. Is there a way to easily rsync the remaining files that are not already backed up to the first drive? I cannot copy the files from the first drive to the second drive first due to time constraints (slow transfer rate).

Comment: Food for thought:  if you can't make a full back-up in your desired time-frame you probably can't restore quickly enough either. - In other words: consider simply making a full back-up from your internal drive to the large external drive and avoid doing complicated things like making a list of files already on your first drive and using that list in the [rsync option](https://www.unix.com/man-page/redhat/1/rsync/) `--exclude-from=FILE`  when copying your data to the second drive.

Comment: Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers.